# Updating multiple android apps from master git branch

Tags: android, git, build, apk

I currently have over 30 apps on Google Play and their branches all descend from the master branch. 
The problem is that when updating the master branch with 1 feature and / or bug fix, i have to go through all apps and merge changes, build the apk and publish the store.

Given that publishing to the store has to be done manually. Are there any easier ways / tools to merge and build APKs for all descendant branches?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Gradle build system includes [Build Variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants). You may be able to have one project that includes your 30 apps, which are then built using variants.